# Что делает "Волшебная" константа __DIR__

Tags: php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам вопрос в `__DIR__`, эта константа указывает на на директорию в которой находится что ?

Comment: а что Вам мешает посмотреть, что выводит константа?

Comment: ну так то да , но я фиг знает , но спасибо что пнули в нужное направление

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это директория того файла, в котором в данный момент исполняется код:

```
/var/www/test-app/index.php:

<?php
echo __DIR__; // /var/www/test-app
```

---

```
/var/www/test-app/subdir/sub-test.php:

<?php
echo __DIR__; // /var/www/test-app/subdir
```

`__FILE__` аналогичным образом вернет вам путь до исполняемого в данный момент файла (т.е. `basename(__FILE__) === __DIR__`)

Comment: а в каком случае это удобно ?

Comment: @LenovoID это уже отдельный вопрос. Но вообще другим способом сложно найти, где расположено ваше текущее приложение. Например, чтобы подгрузить соседний скрипт из родительской папки, я могу сделать `include dirname(__DIR__) . '/script.php'`, хотя это не очень правильный подход. Обычно это помогает однократно найти корень приложения (с разрешением всех симлинков) и временами помогает в дебаге.

Comment: т.е это аналогично что писать полный путь без этих констант ?

Comment: @LenovoID вы физически не можете знать полный путь до запуска скрипта. А вот к `__DIR__` обратиться можете.

Comment: так к нему что от фонаря обращаться можно ?

Comment: @LenovoID зависит от ваших интенций

Answer (score 4):

`__DIR__` возвращает директорию выполняемого скрипта.

Например у вас есть скрипт `/usr/www/site/html/index.php`. Вы в нем пишите

```
echo __DIR__;
```

`__DIR__` вернет путь папки в которой находится это скрипт, `/usr/www/site/html`

Comment: Например у вас есть скрипт /usr/www/site/html/index.php. Вы в нем пишите `echo __DIR__`, `__DIR__` вернет путь папки в которой находится это скрипт /usr/www/site/html

Answer (score -1):

Если вы поставите свой скрипт на cron и у вас пути будут без константы **DIR** и аналогов, то скрипт не найдёт нужные файлы. хотя при ручном запуске всё будет ок.